# Reorder Items in DIV on window resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="data">
    <div class="qa">
        <div class="question">
            Question 1
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            Answer 1
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="qa">
        <div class="question">
            Question 2
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            Answer 2
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="qa">
        <div class="question">
            Question 3
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            Answer 3
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="qa">
        <div class="question">
            Question 4
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            Answer 4
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="qa">
        <div class="question">
            Question 5
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            Answer 5
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="qa">
        <div class="question">
            Question 6
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            Answer 6
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="qa">
        <div class="question">
            Question 7
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            Answer 7
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="qa">
        <div class="question">
            Question 8
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            Answer 8
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="qa">
        <div class="question">
            Question 9
        </div>
        <div class="answer">
            Answer 9
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Above is some basic HTML that shows what I want to be in three columns when above a certain window width. However, when the user resizes the window I need the columns to go to 2 columns. So in the first variation of the table it would be:

Question 1: Answer 1 | Question 4: Answer 4 | Question 7: Answer 7
Question 2: Answer 2 | Question 5: Answer 5 | Question 8: Answer 8
Question 3: Answer 3 | Question 6: Answer 6 | Question 9: Answer 9

And for the smaller screen the grid should reorder to something like below.

Question 1: Answer 1 | Question 6: Answer 6
Question 2: Answer 2 | Question 7: Answer 7
Question 3: Answer 3 | Question 8: Answer 8
Question 4: Answer 4 | Question 9: Answer 9
Question 5: Answer 5 |

Note that I need the data to be columns not rows. I have been trying to use everything from bootstrap to custom javascript and I still cannot get this to work. The data is originally built with C# and I need this to work on the client side and be cross browser friendly. Below is some code that I have been trying to get to work and it sort of works, but I am stuck. Is there a better way? I am sure there is.

http://jsfiddle.net/MKL4g/624/

```
if (typeof jQuery === 'undefined') {
    throw new Error('Resizable Columns requires jQuery.');
}

+ function($) {
    var version = $.fn.jquery.split(' ')[0].split('.');
    if ((version[0] < 2 && version[1] < 9) ||
        (version[0] === 1 && version[1] === 9 && version[2] < 1) || (version[0] > 3)) {
        throw new Error('Resizable Columns requires jQuery version 1.9.1 or higher, but lower than version 4.');
    }
}(jQuery);

function ResizeColumns(data, width, numCols) {
    this.data = data;
    this.width = width;
    this.noCols = numCols;
    this.resize = function() {
        if (width < 768) {
            this.noCols = 2;
        }
        if (data === undefined || data === null) {
            throw new Error('data is empty!');
        }
        if (this.data === undefined || this.data === null) {
            throw new Error('this.data is empty!');
        }
        logMessages('before max');
        var max = Math.ceil(this.data.length / this.noCols);
        var colArray = [];
        var msgs = '';
        msgs += 'data.length = ' + this.data.length;
        msgs += '<br />max = ' + max;
        msgs += '<br />width = ' + this.width;
        msgs += '<br />noCols = ' + this.noCols;
        logMessages(msgs, false);
        colArray = chunkArrayInGroups(data, max);
        msgs += '<br />colArray.length = ' + colArray.length;
        for (var i = 0; i < colArray.length; i++) {
            if (i === 0) {
                $('#data').after('<div class="section" id="section' + i + '"></div>')
            } else {
                var tmp = i - 1;
                $('#section' + tmp).after('<div class="section" id="section' + i + '"></div>')
            }
            var colData = colArray[i];
            for (var j = 0; j < colData.length; j++) {
                $('#section' + i).append(colData[j])
            }
        }

    };

    function chunkArrayInGroups(array, unit) {
        var results = [],
            length = Math.ceil(array.length / unit);

        for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            results.push(array.slice(i * unit, (i + 1) * unit));
        }
        return results;
    };
};

function logMessages(msg, useConsole) {
    if (useConsole) {
        window.console && console.log(msg);
    } else {
        $('#msgs').html(msg);
    }
}

//$(document).ready(function() {
//  GetData();
//  var data = $("body").data("data");
//  var rc = new ResizeColumns(data, $(window).width(), 3);
//  rc.resize();
//});

function GetData() {
    var data = $("body").data("data");
    if (data === null || data === undefined) {
        data = $('#data').find('.qa');
        if (data !== null && data !== undefined) {
            $("body").data("data", data);
        } else {
            logMessages('No data loaded', true);
        }
    } else {
        logMessages('Data loaded via jquery.data()', true);
    }
}

var $window = $(window);
var width = $window.width();
$(window).on({
    load: function() {
        logMessages('load method');

    },
    resize: function() {
        setInterval(function() {
            if (width != $window.width()) {
                width = $window.width();
                GetData();
                var data = $("body").data("data");
                var rc = new ResizeColumns(data, width, 3);
                rc.resize();
            }
        }, 300);
    }
});
```

Comment: Your code is so confusing according to what you say you need in the first place. Take a look at this fiddle. No JavaScript or CSS at all. Just bootstrap. http://jsfiddle.net/MKL4g/631/. Resize the window and take a look at the result.

Comment: @Tsalikidis In your example you have Question 2 being part of the second column, I need it to be in column one unless there is only two questions.

Comment: It's just text you can change it :P

Answer (score 0):

Use bootstrap to manipulate the layout depending on the screen size.

All you gotta do is add the class name. For reference check [this](http://getbootstrap.com/css/)

Comment: My problem with bootstrap is how does the columns get resorted? How does the Question 4 and Question 5 get moved to column 1?

Comment: @stanley check **Column ordering** in the above link

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try to display it as flex.
Here is a nice and easy tutorial how to do it. I learned how to make flex displays from it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G7EIAgfkhmg

And you can set order for nth-child as you want.

Answer (score 0):

A super simple way to do it would be to create two separate divs with your questions and answers how you need them to be, then use the bootstrap sizing to show/hide the entire set of questions at different resolutions. That would give you a lot more control over the layout because you would no longer be relying on how the individual pieces flow across screen sizes.

Akash' answer could be made to work, but it sounds like a pretty big hassle and will only become more so as requirements change, questions are added and removed, etc...

Answer (score 0):

[That's what you need](https://jsfiddle.net/ok72tmLp/). In `devices > medium` you break the columns into more pieces.

But of course this is a static example just to understand how bootstrap grid works and how it can help you in your case.